# asp.net Gridview with date selection

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a simple gridview that I would like to use to update a SQL table.  I have the gridview set up using template fields.  The first 5 columns are data report fields like customer, job name etc.  These fields will not be editable.  The next fields are all date fields.  The user will edit a row and add the date for the activity.  The first column is import date, so the user would enter 12/4/2013.  I was thinking it would be nice to have a date picker.  With over 10 stages that need to be reported, this may make the edit very difficult.  So in lieu of a date picker is there a way to check that the user has entered a valid date format at the time of entry?  If the user entered 12/4/2013 (US date format), this would be acceptable.  But if they entered 12/32/2013 it would reject the date as not a valid date?

Below is the code for how I have the template fields set up in the gridview for the first 5 columns.  I was hoping to use this to create the edit templates.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pages">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblPages" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pages")%>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
<ItemStyle Width="60px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Any client-side date picker plugin/widget/etc. would handle the date picking functionality (such as the jQuery UI Datepicker).  You'll still want to validate all of the input server-side though.  For any given string input that should be a date, you'd want to use something like `DateTime.TryParse()` to make sure it's a valid date.  There are some server-side date picker components (I don't know of any free ones) which would handle this validation internally for you.  Or something like model binding in ASP.NET MVC would strongly-type the date input for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [`CompareValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the [`Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.operator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to `DataTypeCheck` and the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to `Date`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ImportDate" runat="server" ... />

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="ImportDate"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Date"
    Display="Dynamic"
    Text="*"
    ErrorMessage="Import date is invalid"
    ToolTip="Please enter a valid date"
/>
```